# Binary compare operation in elegant way

Tags: c++

I need to check is `b` byte 1'st bit is ON and if yes is last 2 bits (.6 and .7) are also ON. How to make it in most elegant way?

```
bool myStatus::isReady()
{
    return ((b&0x01) && (b&0xC0==0)) ;
}
```

Elegant means most readable without loosing performance

Comment: This is probably a much better question on: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Last 2 bits ON or OFF?  Your words and your code disagree.

Comment: What's the difference between, `if bit[0] is on, if bit[6] and bit[7] on`, to, `if bit[0], bit[6] and bit[7] on`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
bool myStatus::isReady() const
{
    static auto const mask = 0b11000001; // Or 0xC1
    return (b & mask) == mask;
}
```

This is equivalent to your description but not your solution. An equivalent of your code would have to change the right operand of the comparison to `1`, i.e.

```
return (b & mask) == 1;
```

Also note that solutions without braces are wrong since `&` has a lower precedence than `==`.

Answer (score 3):

Either `return (b&0xC1)==0xC1;` if you really meant all bits ON like you stated.
Otherwise `return (b&0xC1)==0x01;` if you want an equivalent to what you coded.

Comment: Thanks for (b&0xC1)==0xC1. But can't understand why ((b&0x01) && (b&0xC0==0)) is the same like (b&0xC1)==0x01? According to my understanding my mistakable code always returns 0

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return (b & 0xC1) == 0x01;
```

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, it matches the code given in the question even if it doesn't match the description. But that's the OP's problem, not yours.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I see now, the description above the code doesn't match the code. The problem is in the question itself...

Comment: You forgot the braces. Operator precedence is the problem.

Comment: @Loopunroller: To the best of my knowledge, all arithmetic operators precede all comparison operators.

Comment: @barakmanos This is not an arithmetic but a bitwise operator.
Check it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
bool myStatus::isReady()
{
    return (b & 0xc0) && (b & 0x1);
}
```

http://numbermonk.com/binary/193

Comment: This will return true for any of those bits set.

Comment: @dariogriffo let b = 0x01, function will return true. Also 0xc0 will return true. Also 0x80 will return true...

Comment: @dariogriffo now it matches OP description but it's same code he posted (but it's _wrong_ if instead of his description we look at his code).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Is not my fault he has a bug on his code, his requirement is explicit.